# Using ReadTheDocs to host Sphinx Docs created with Jupyter

Tags: jupyter, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I continue to have failed builds with ReadTheDocs using a github repository with Jupyter notebooks rendered using sphinx and the readthedocs theme.  I am able to render these locally, however when I try with RTD, I get the following fail message:

[image]

I tried placing the nbsphinx.py file in the repository but things still fail.  Link to RTD is here:

https://readthedocs.org/projects/calculus-notes/

Github repo is here:

https://github.com/jfkoehler/calc_docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RTD needs to install `nbsphinx`.  To tell RTD to install packages, you must:

1. From [RTD FAQ, My project isn’t building with autodoc](http://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#my-project-isn-t-building-with-autodoc):

   > enable the virtualenv feature in the Admin page of your project, which will install your project into a virtualenv, and allow you to specify a `requirements.txt` file for your project.
2. Create `requirements.txt` in your repo and add `nbsphinx` to its contents.  See https://github.com/spatialaudio/nbsphinx/blob/0.2.14/doc/requirements.txt#L2

After you commit and push item 2 to your repo, then RTD should install `nbsphinx` and be able to build your docs successfully, or at least proceed to the next failure if there is one.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks so much.