# Read The Docs don't show any functions when using automodule

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I’ve got a problem visualizing the documentation of my project in Read the Docs. Everything works fine locally by executing the command `make html`, but in Read the Docs the functions that should be generated by the directive automodule don’t show up.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvmEM.png) is how my repository is structured.

In the **conf.py** I set the absolute path as follows: `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))`, and then I used the following instruction for automatically describing the functions contained in the Python module in my documentation:

```
.. automodule:: library.module1
    :members:
```

However, no functions are shown by compiling the doc in Read The Docs. 
I also tried to install my project in a *virtualenv* by specifying a **requirements.txt** file in the RTD advanced settings, but this doesn’t work either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Provide a link to the build log on RTD. It will say why it cannot build your docs. I suspect that you have not followed all the necessary steps. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/46995305/2214933 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/45316259/2214933

Comment: Here's the link to the build log: https://readthedocs.org/projects/genereg/builds/7814214/. The build is successful, but functions are not shown in the documentation.

Comment: The build log's UI is an "accordion". Click on the first instance of `python /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/genereg/envs/latest/bin/sphinx-build -T -...` to see details. RTD did not import your package because you did not follow all the steps as I mentioned previously. There should be an accordion with both something like `python /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/pyramid/envs/latest/bin/pip install --exists-action=w --cache-dir /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/pyramid/.cache/pip -r rtd.txt` and `python setup.py install --force`

Comment: I tried using a requirements.txt file (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kia23/genereg/master/requirements.txt) as suggested in the links provided above, installing the project in a virtualenv, but most of the packages specified fail to be imported, returning in the build log (https://readthedocs.org/projects/genereg/builds/7861471/) the error "could not find a version that satisfies the requirement".

Comment: Perhaps it's a Python requirement mismatch? Your package requires >=3.6, while RTD uses 3.5. The only other reason I can imagine is a temporary network or PyPI outage. Sorry I'm not much more help here.